# How to create complex dependent dropdown using VBA in Excel 2016?

Tags: vba, excel, dropdown

I have the following data in a worksheet called Parts.

[image: Parts Worksheet]

In a *different* worksheet called Planning, I have the following data:

[image: Planning Worksheet]

In the above Planning Worksheet, Cell D3 is a dropdown that allow to choose a display language. The current choices are "English" and "Japanese". The A column's cells are also dropdown that allow to select a dimension.

What I want to do is create a dropdown that:

1. is dependent on the cell in the A column. The dropdown **should filtered** data from the Parts Worksheet according to the value of the corresponding A cell.
2. is also dependent on the D3 Cell. The dropdown **should display** "English description" if D3 is "English" or "Japanese description" if D3 is "Japanese"
3. once selected, the data in the dropdown **should be the Part and not the description**. In other words, it should behave like a select tag in HTML.

I am new to VBA and after quite a lot of searching, I can't figure out how to do this. I would really appreciate a detailed answer. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

The final Parts Worksheet will be at least 10,000 lines long. The user can't create named list manually. For this reason, I think I should use VBA.

Comment: This is easily done with worksheet functions, is there a particular reason why you want to use VBA?

Comment: See [Dependent Drop Down Lists](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)

Comment: @CallumDA If you could point me to the right direction, this would be great!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thank you for the link. I will check and try!

Comment: I want to use VBA, because the ultimate Parts Worksheet will contain more than 10,000 lines and the user can't create named list manually. It would be great to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you tried this when I posted it as an answer on your question from yesterday.

The code does everything that you need by creating a validation dropdown on-the-fly based on the value in column A when you select a cell on column B.  The dropdown displays the product code and the description depending on the language.  The description is removed once a product code has been selected and the validation is removed from the cell.

While the code does do everything that you require it's not perfect but it gives you a huge head start and it should work with your sheet names etc. if you copy and paste it and give it a try.

```
Dim CHANGING_VAL As Boolean 'Global Variable that can be set to prevent the onchange being fired when the Macro is removing the description from the dropdown.

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)


    If Target.Column = 2 And CHANGING_VAL = False Then
        CHANGING_VAL = True
        If InStr(1, Target.Value, "~") > 2 Then
            Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, InStr(1, Target.Value, "~") - 2)
        End If
        Target.Validation.Delete
        Target.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        CHANGING_VAL = False
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        If Target.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
            strValidList = ""
            For intRow = 1 To 10000
                If Sheets("Parts").Cells(intRow, 1) = Target.Offset(0, -1) Then
                    If Sheets(Target.Parent.Name).Cells(3, 4) = "English" Then
                        strValidList = strValidList & Sheets("Parts").Cells(intRow, 2) & " ~ " & Sheets("Parts").Cells(intRow, 3) & ", "
                    Else
                        strValidList = strValidList & Sheets("Parts").Cells(intRow, 2) & " ~ " & Sheets("Parts").Cells(intRow, 4) & ", "
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            If strValidList <> "" Then
                strValidList = Left(strValidList, Len(strValidList) - 2)

                Target.Select

                With Selection.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=strValidList
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = ""
                    .ErrorTitle = ""
                    .InputMessage = ""
                    .ErrorMessage = ""
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Else
        Sheets(Target.Parent.Name).Range("B:B").Validation.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you! But I would actually love to have an explanation of this code in case I have to make changes.

Comment: I figured out your code! It works really nicely. I learned a lot!