# Distinct Values based on two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I must be tired because I feel like I've done this before, but just banging my head tonight.
Anyway, I have a data sheet. 10 columns 800 rows. ( an excel table if you will)

On a separate sheet I have various drop downs. I want to be able to have a drop down that is based on the first 2 selections the user makes.

So If in cell A2 user selects 10 and in cell B2 user selects 12 , I want to be able to filter the excel table for values in Column D, based on the 2 values selected beforehand.

I've looked at formulas and doing data validation. I'm using the data validation for cells A2 and B2, however they are just list.

I tried a 3rd data validation using an If statement, but that continues to fail.

datasheet could contain:

```
column1 |column2 | column3|etc...
10      | 12     | 22
11      | 13     | 23
11      | 33     | 23
10      | 12     | 25
11      | 13     | 24
10      | 12     | 26
```

What I think should work, something like:

```
if(A2=10, list1, list2)
```

My issue is list 1 is where I need to select distinct values from column 3 based on filtering items from columns 1 & 2, but I cant get it to work to save my life...

When I try to do the formulas as listed above, it barfs telling me I need a delimited list...

Just looking for pointers in the right direction. Like I said , I feel like I've done this before, just can't recall it tonight. Thanks in advance for any direction. Respectfully.

Comment: Might be a bit of different direction, but can you use Slicers? Built in table filters which exclude prior selections from other filtered Slicers (when set to Hide Items with No Data).

Comment: Something like this? [link](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)

Comment: Something like the link. Issue is my data is not as cut and dry as the example. columns 1,2 & 3 also contain other various pieces of data, related, but not useful in this situation. The pieces of data I want to use for this set of drop downs in in the middle of my excel data. (Does that make sense?)

Comment: I looked at the link, Thank you Xabier.  It's not exactly like what I am looking for. I did find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510322/how-to-create-complex-dependent-dropdown-using-vba-in-excel-2016) which @Gordon replied with something I think will most likely work with some editing.